# What's the difference between "verursachen" and "bedingen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning

Seems both words mean "to cause"; what's the difference?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary? What did you find? Why isn't the information not sufficient?

Comment: @userunknown Obviously they both had the entry of "cause" and nothing more. Else why would I ask? Though indeed there is more information in a German-German dictionary, I only looked at German-English dictionaries at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> durch etwas bedingt
>
> durch etwas verursacht

Both means caused by something.

But the first expresses the necessity of the condition expressed in *durch etwas*, while the second can easily include causation by happen chance.

> durch die Rezession bedingt

Would be translated

> caused by, or better, induced by the recession

One could see this clearly in these examples

*bedingt entlassen* means on parole, let go from prison with conditions, and conditions would be translated *Bedingungen*.

*Verursachen* says that something caused something (cause = *Ursache*), but one might only know in hindsight, because the cause was not a condition, just a catalyst or trigger.

Comment: "bedingt entlassen" is not a good example, imho. Different word class.

Comment: I do think that it gives an idea about the semantic field of the word *begingen*, from which *bedingt* derives. The difference of the two words is in their semantic field.